# findstr from matlab for python

Tags: python, matlab

I would like translate this code from Matlab(below) for Python v2.7.5. Can you help me?

```
fseek (fid,128,'bof');
offset = fread (fid,1,'ushort');
while (offset > 0)
freeString = setstr (fread (fid,offset-2,'char'))';
if (findstr (freeString,'ACQUISITION_DATE') > 0)
  date_rec=(freeString (length ('ACQUISITION_DATE '):length (freeString)));
end;
if (findstr (freeString,'ACQUISITION_TIME') > 0)
  time_rec=(freeString (length ('ACQUISITION_TIME '):length (freeString)));
end;
if (findstr (freeString,'GENERAL_CONSTANT') > 0)
  gen_const_rec=(freeString (length ('GENERAL_CONSTANT '):length (freeString)));
```

Thank you,
Samuel

Comment: What did you try yourself so far?

Comment: There is no `end` in the code you show, and the value of `offset` doesn't appear to change inside the `while` loop. As such it would never terminate (although it might not run). Usually one would use `if` for that. Are you sure this code fragment is correct/complete?

Comment: Or based on the title and despite the code dump, is the question simply what the Python equivalent of `findstr(input_str,'test_str') > 0` is?

Answer (score 0):

Based on the suggestion from @horchler, you probably just need the `in` operator:

```
print ("hello" in "hello world")

>> True

print ("hello" in "goodbye")

>> False

print ("hello" in "world, hello")

>> True
```

In other words, the equivalent of Matlab's

```
if (findstr (freeString,'ACQUISITION_DATE') > 0)
```

is

```
if ('ACQUISITION_DATE' in freeString):
```

Note - findstr (which will be removed in a future version of Matlab) will find "the shorter string in the longer one" - while for the Python `in` operator, the order of operands matters.